# How to set height 1px of <td>

Tags: css, html

Hi I have trouble with my table structure in IE browser. I want to set height 1px to td but it  is not happing in IE. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auwcV/) attached

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <head>
    .listSep { border-top:1px #000000 solid; height:1px; margin:0; padding:0}
    </style>



</head>
<body>
    <table width="664" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="border:solid 1px #FF0000; font-size:0px; line-height:0px" height="1"><hr class="listSep"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: Which IE? Works fine in IE9... maybe choose not to support IE8 (if that one is the problem)?

Comment: why is the table outside the body ?

Comment: @rune: check in quirks mode in ie

Comment: @amit good point. I don't support IE8 anymore these days so I totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure is invalid. Your `body` starts within the `head`. And you are missing the `style` start tag.

You have:

```
    .listSep { border-top:1px #000000 solid; height:1px; margin:0; padding:0}
    </style>
<body>
</head>

<!-- more code -->
</body>
```

Change it to:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .listSep { border-top:1px #000000 solid; height:1px; margin:0; padding:0}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- more code -->
</body>
```